# In a dual socket -- Linux using CPU Socket 1 and some-other-program running on CPU Socket 2 -- how to prevent memory region overlaps

Tags: linux, cpu, mmu

I'm reading about Operating system privilege levels and how the CPU's MMU in cooperation with the OS, prevents invalid memory access.

I think I understand how that works, but I fail to understand how that would work if there is another non-OS running on Socket 1 while Linux is just running on Socket 1.

My question is as follows:

1. Is it not possible to run this configuration -- Linux just given control of CPU Socket 1 when booting up OS and a different OS(program) takes control of CPU Socket 2.
2. If yes, then how do you prevent these two OSs (or Linux and the other program) from stomping on overlapping regions of memory
3. How does privilege level security work in this case?

Comment: Sounds a bit like https://github.com/siemens/jailhouse

Comment: *" if there is another non-OS running on Socket 1 while Linux is just running on Socket 1."* Typo?? Socket 1 and Socket 2?

Comment: Jailhouse still assumes that you have a central controlling Authority. If there is one, like Jailhouse, then it can be handled, however, in the above mentioned configuration, how is it handled? Or is it impossible to setup the machine in that particular way? Does OS1 prevent OS2 from claiming the other CPU Socket?

Comment: Socket 1 runs at boot.  If it chooses to dedicate socket 2 to a program and let it access memory it is free to do so.  It could run a second OS in a VM, but I don't think there's a way to run two independent OS on the two sockets.

Comment: The only option is an IO-MMU, like Intel VT-d. The CPUs are considered peers. Anyway, running two OSes is not generally possible unless one customizes the firmware (or uses a VMM) and that's a specific use case that generally means cooperation between the OSes.